# How to refresh the expired access token with out login to office 365 using token cache already saved in a database using V2 model?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, office365

Hi I'm tring to build a windows form application to access the office 365 APIs using V2 model. I just want to know how to refresh the expired access token with out login to office 365, but using token cache already saved in a database. The token cache save through a MVC web project to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Since the web application store multiple users, which user you want to login in form the Windows form? If you want to login the windows form with specific user, it is same as refresh the token in the web app using **AcquireTokenSilentAsync** method.

Comment: Yes. That's correct Fei Xue. Thanks for your answer.